# Git merge - Already up-to-date

Tags: git, git-merge

I've got two branches 1) feature/X 2) release/Y , both created from develop branch. Both are long running and have multiple commits. 
To bring all the changes in release/Y into feature/X , we did this 
 
`git checkout feature/X` 
`git pull --all`. 
`git merge release/Y`. 
 Some conflicts showed up, which were resolved and then the `git commit and push` was done.
However, later we found that lot of changes in release/Y are missing from feature/X. 
Now, any attempt of `git merge release/Y` from feature/X shows 'Already up-to-date'.

git diff also shows lots of changes and conflicts.

What went wrong in the merge? Was the merge done in a wrong way?
Is there a way to resolve this situation?

Comment: Never use `git pull --all`: it passes `--all` to `git fetch`, where it does something that is clearly not what you expected. I advise avoiding `git pull` entirely, at least until you are very familiar with both `git fetch` and `git merge`.

Comment: I don't know what went wrong, but you might get some clues with `git log --name-status` to look at the filenames in the problematic commit. Perhaps git did not commit those files for some reason? Maybe a mistake was made during the manual conflict resolution. If you can figure out what happened, someone here can probably tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Also, `git reflog` can tell you a lot about what git was doing at that time.